# why formdata is always empty? fullstack problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, multer, react-fullstack

I am trying to use it to send `img` to `multer` in node to upload the `img` but always get me a `null`

I tryed to restart the whole project but nothing

here front part :

```
const addPostsHundler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const form = new FormData().append("file", file);

  console.log(data.user_id);

  axios
    .post("http://localhost:5000/Upload", {
      form: form,
      inputs: input,
      userID: data.user_id,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

and back part :

```
const multer = require("multer");

let fileName;

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "../client/public/upload");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    fileName = file.originalname;
    cb(null, fileName);
  },
});

app.post("/Upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: "img stored", img: fileName });
});
```